# When was handleError removed from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, handleerror

I'm revisiting some old code, and have found it doesn't work with jQuery 1.6 because it cannot find `$.handleError()`.  A quick search of the jQuery code shows nothing, so I guess this function has been removed/replaced.

Does anyone know which version the handleError function was first missing from, and if it has a direct replacement?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like `handleError()` was removed in jQuery 1.5. Most solutions I've seen online [create their own error functions](http://blogs.cozi.com/tech/2008/04/javascript-error-tracking-why-windowonerror-is-not-enough.html). Hope that helps

Comment: +1. It's worth mentioning that the method was never documented (therefore, never really part of the official API), which is probably why there was nothing about the method's removal in the 1.5 release notes.

Comment: The lack of documentation is what's annoying me!