# ajaxFileUpload on xhr.setRequestHeader is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, backbone.js

In my footer.php I have this code which i needed for my api references

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /** Override ajaxSend so we can add the api key for every call **/
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) 
  {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("<?php echo $this->config->item('rest_key_name');?>", "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('api_key')?>");
  });
</script>
```

It works fine in my project without any error but when I started working on file upload and I'm using ajaxfileupload to upload file, I got this error whenever i upload the file.

```
TypeError: xhr.setRequestHeader is not a function   
xhr.setRequestHeader("KEY", "123456POIUMSSD");
```

Here is my ajaxfileuplod program code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var DocsMasterView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#documents-info"),
        initialize: function () {  

        },
        events: {
            'submit' : 'test'
        },
        test: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var request = $.ajaxFileUpload({
                url             :'./crew-upload-file',
                secureuri       :false,
                fileElementId   :'userfile',
                dataType        : 'json',
                data            : {
                'title'           : $('#title').val()
                },
                success  : function (data, status)
                {
                    if(data.status != 'error')
                    {
                       $('#files').html('<p>Reloading files...</p>');
                       refresh_files();
                       $('#title').val('');

                    }
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            });

            request.abort();
            return false;

        }
    });
    var x = new DocsMasterView();

});
</script>
```

Can anyone here fix my problem. Any suggestion/advice in order to solve my problem.

Comment: Try to do a simple ajax call (something like `$.ajax({...}`) instead of `$.ajaxFileUpload()`). Not sure how that uploader works, but if it is based on iFrames only, it may fail to provide setRequestHeader with jqXhr (because you can't add a header in case if upload is based on iFrame)

Comment: not possible it returning "aborted"

Comment: What returns aborted? Check network tab and see request headers for your simple ajax request.

Comment: This is the ouput on my request header: Accept 
application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Host localhost
KEY 123456POIUMSSD
Referer http://localhost/fsc/crew-test
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Do you have a control on server side code?

Comment: yes. I'm the developer of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your comments, `setRequestHeaders` works fine with regular ajax calls.  At the same time it is not available when `ajaxFileUpload` is used. Most likely that is because transport method does not allow to set headers (for instance, in case when iframe is used to emulate upload of files in ajax style) . So, possible solution is to place a key into your form data:

```
 $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) 
  {
      if(xhr.setRequestHeader) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("<?php echo $this->config->item('rest_key_name');?>", "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('api_key')?>");
       else
          options.data["<?php echo $this->config->item('rest_key_name');?>"] = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('api_key')?>";
  });
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if options.data is a correct statement, just do not remember structure of options object. If proposed code does not work - try to do `console.log(options)` and how 
to get an object with data that should be posted (it might be something like `options.formData`, I just do not remember exactly)

And on server side you will just need to check for key in headers or form data.

Comment: It works fine now. uploading is now working but there still error I can't figure out. " TypeError: jQuery.handleError is not a function
jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e); "

Comment: try this: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/. As far as I can see, handleError [removed from jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6329656/1558311)